# How can you set it up so that your project automatically updates on your production server when you make changes to a github repository?

Tags: git, github

I just started working with another developer and we were talking about different version control solution so our projects will go smoother. We decided that git was the best option since we both knew how to use it already. What we want to do is set up a github repository that automatically syncs with the production server when we make changes. Is there a way to do this? Just looking for a point in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want to A/ export the latest source to production (but no coding happens on production server) ? B/ sync two git repositories, one of them on github, both featuring some development ?

Comment: Leaning more towards B. I don't want to touch the code on the server. I just want it to sync with whatever the latest update is on the master branch of a github repo. I like the workflow that heroku offers for rails. I want to accomplish the same workflow, but on my own server.

Comment: Plus, I am not using rails. I am doing php development. Otherwise I would just use heroku. Just found phpfog. Thinking about using something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have github communicate to a remote host when you push to your repo:
  http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/

So you can then write your own request handler to accept the JSON that they post to you, and kick off the process of updating a server-side checkout of the repo, and somehow updating itself. Some care may need to go into making sure that the server doesn't misconfigure itself while taking an update, but if you're just updating PHP files you should be OK.

That is, you just that the "ref" is equal to "refs/heads/master", and if so, cd to where your PHP files are checked out and do `git fetch github`, `git reset --hard $after_rev`.