# Github automatic sync

Tags: github

I want to set up a web server on a VPS server and I decided Github would be a good way to version and have access from different locations.

Is there a way to have a git command line client auto sync, so when I make a commit in the repository, it will update on the server (preferably instantly)?

**Edit:** I am trying to get a remote server to automatically pull the changes of a GitHub repository when it is updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you set it up so that your project automatically updates on your production server when you make changes to a github repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797982/how-can-you-set-it-up-so-that-your-project-automatically-updates-on-your-product)

Comment: It is indeed; however it won't let me mark duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so when I make a commit in the repository, it will update on the server

It is call [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), which act as a post-update hook on GitHub side, and generates a [JSON payload](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads) that your server can listen to.

The page "[Delivering deployments](https://developer.github.com/guides/delivering-deployments/)" illustrates several deployment techniques:

> The [Deployments API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/deployments/) provides your projects hosted on GitHub with the capability to launch them on a server that you own.
>   Combined with the [Status API](https://developer.github.com/guides/building-a-ci-server), you’ll be able to coordinate your deployments the moment your code lands on `master`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am a bit of a noob with Github by the command line. Could you explain it in more detail and will this work with html files, css, js, etc.?

Comment: It's not all command line: you have to declare the webhook on the GitHub site first.